# Get wordpress posts from certain category if statement

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to get wordpress posts belonging to a certain category if a condition is met.
So basically there is a `select` dropdown where the user chooses a category. Once they haven chosen said category I want to display the posts of that category, so something like:

```
<script>
var postID = "Case Study"  // category name

jQuery("#test").change(function(){
    if(jQuery(this).val()==postID){
         // get the posts of the category that is equal to Case Study
    }
});
</script>
```

I know how to do this if it was just one category i.e Case study, however as they have got the choice from several categories I need to somehow match the selected category and post only the posts from that category.

Any ideas?

Comment: if you want to get posts after something has happened on screen you are going to need to use AJAX - note that ajax works slightly differently with wordpress https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/

Comment: Do you need to retrieve and work with the data using jQuery? It would be much easier using PHP.

Comment: doesn't have to be jQuery, just need the change event